# How to call aws service to asynchronously in python aws lambda

Tags: python, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I need to call to async function inside lambda function. When executing this, it's showing this error

```
await wasn't used with future
```

Here is my code

```
async def main():
    bucketName = 'data-store-test'
    folder = 'Contacts-Aggre'
    lastModifiedFolderPath = await  getLastModifiedBucketPath(bucketName,folder)
    print('Received lastModifiedFolderPath:',lastModifiedFolderPath)
     
async def getLastModifiedBucketPath(bucketName, prefix):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    bucket_objects = await asyncio.gather(*loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(s3_client.list_objects_v2, Bucket=bucketName, Prefix=prefix)))
    all = bucket_objects['Contents']        
    latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
    folderPaths = latest['Key'].split('/')
    lastModifiedFolder = folderPaths[1] if len(folderPaths) >=2 else folderPaths[0]
    return lastModifiedFolder

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

What is the issue in this code? I created another question also related to this. No one answered for me, that's why I created this.

In this **getLastModifiedBucketPath** method used to get specific bucket location last modified folder name. If I remove asyncio.gather part, then it's working. But I need to return value after it execute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning asyncio this week, so take this with a grain of salt, but my belief is:

- `loop.run_in_executor` returns a future
- This future is not awaited; when you try to splat it, you get the error (try out just that snippet in your REPL and you'll see)
- `gather` needs the splatted argument to be a list, not a future

Try awaiting that `run_in_executor` before using it as an argument to gather and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done this. I'll put my code here when I have a free time. These days bit busy with my tasks